# Does epimorphism from a proper subgroup onto G imply isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Does the existence of an epimorphism from a proper subgroup $P$ of $G$ onto $G$ imply that $P$ is isomorphic to $G$? In general, the answer is negative. What if $G$ has arbitrarily high rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Tom Leinster's answer to [this Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3), A. L. S. Corner constructed a countable Abelian group $G$ such that $G\cong G^3\not\cong G^2.$ Thus $G$ has a proper subgroup $H$ which is isomorphic to $G^2,$ and there is a surjective homomorphism from $H$ to $G,$ but $H$ is not isomorphic to $G.$

Answer (score 3):

No, let $G$ be a free group of rank $2$. Then $G$ contains as subgroups
free groups of any countable rank, so for instance a free subgroup $P$
of rank $3$. There is an epimorphism from $P$ to $G$, but they are not isomorphic.

Comment: Do you know of a non free group example?

Comment: @DionelJaime Let $K$ be any (nontrivial) countable group and let $F_2$ be a free group of rank $2.$ Then $H=F_2\times K$ is a countable group, so it is a subgroup of some $2$-generator group $G,$ and there is a surjective homomorphism from $H$ to $G,$ but $H$ is not isomorphic to $G.$